# Private chat with signalR and angular

Tags: angular, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm using signalR to create a message chat private between customer and admin(for customer support)

The customer will be a mobile app sending a message to admin will be a web app(I'm ok with that). But now I want if Admin1 send to customer the message will show in Admin2 screen

[image]

Two method to customer send message to all admin, and admin send private message to specific customer

```
public async Task AdminSendMessageToCustomer(ChatHubRequestModel requestModel)
{
    await Clients.Client(requestModel.ConId).AdminSendMessageToCustomer(requestModel)
}

public async Task CustomerSendMessageToAdmin(ChatHubRequestModel request)
{
    await Clients.All.CustomerSendMessageToAdmin(request);
}
```

You guys can give me some keyword to find out, Tks for your time